# Слайдшоу на Чистом Css

Tags: html, html5, css3

Всем привет, может кто нибудь подсказать слайдер на чистом CSS без Javascript , который будет автоматически менять изображения в блоке по времени а также будут кнопки переключения изображений вручную.

Ищу , но без Jquery пока не наткнулся ..
Может знает кто уже проверенный и работающий вариант?

Почему css , потому что на css я могу его сделать резиновым , а javascript не особо знаю , поэтому скрипты мешают тянуть изображение.

Comment: По вашим требованиям, вы не найдёте слайдер даже в ближайшем будущем, т.к. только на CSS - это технически сделать нельзя.

Comment: уже нашел, как оказалось можно

Comment: можете показать пример?

Comment: [Пример слайдшоу на css](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/) . Пример взят с [Хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/143025/), там и плюсы и минусы обсуждаются, и подробности. Но это, все таки, больше как концепт, на практике пользоваться не удобно, гибкости меньше и удобства, чем используя JavaScript.

Comment: Вот пример , который нашел , но к сожалению не получается пока сделать его резиновым...

Comment: Andrew Hobbit , да знаю, у меня на сайте именно этот и стоял слайдер и все устраивало, даже резиновым его сделал но там к сожалению кнопок переключения нет , нашел  с кнопками но его пока не могу сделать резиновым..

Comment: может если кто знает, даст ссылку на JavaScript слайдер с кнопками под резиновый дизайн.

Comment: Я в свое время делал нечто похоже своими руками т.к. не нашел готового решения которое бы удовлетворяло требованиям. Вот тут пример http://fevralia.com/art реализовано под angularjs 1.x

Comment: Нашел , очень хороший слайдер на JS , Говорю как человек который вообще не понимает js ,очень легок в позиционировании и масштабировании на сайте , можно подстроить под резину если указать ширину в %
Знание Css больше ничего не надо.
Вот ссылочка , ответил на свой вопрос.
<http://freeams.ru/lessons/lessons-code/kak-sdelat-adaptivnyiy-rezinovyiy-slayder-izobrazheniy-s-pomoshhyu-jquery-i-css3.html>

Comment: Вот хороший [слайдер](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) и [вот](http://bxslider.com/) с кучей параметров и респонсив, а [то](http://freeams.ru/lessons/lessons-code/kak-sdelat-adaptivnyiy-rezinovyiy-slayder-izobrazheniy-s-pomoshhyu-jquery-i-css3.html) вата какая-то.

Comment: Вот посмотри пример: <https://jsfiddle.net/vradionov/341Lbxvq/> Так же там есть ещё один пример.

Comment: он багнутый , если перейти с 1 страницы на 4 ую таймер не обнуляется и по окончанию таймера он переходит на 2ую страницу.

Comment: Плохой, но пример: http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/vDCqd